# AWS S3 special characters encoding

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-s3, url-encoding

I uploaded a picture in my S3 bucket, the filename is `Müller.jpg`.

When I dig into the file properties in the web UI, it gives me the following link:
`https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my_bucket_name/Mu%CC%88ller.jpg`

How can I achieve the same encoding in python 2.x?

```
>>> import urllib
>>> name = u"Müller.jpg"
>>> urllib.quote(name.encode('utf-8'))
'M%C3%BCller.jpg'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the filename is normalized to NFD or NFKD.

Use [`unicodedata.normalize`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize):

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> import urllib
>>> name = u"Müller.jpg"
>>> urllib.quote(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', name).encode('utf-8'))
'Mu%CC%88ller.jpg'
>>> urllib.quote(unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', name).encode('utf-8'))
'Mu%CC%88ller.jpg'
```